# Why doesn't the handlebars "if" helper call the actual model computed property?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm maintaining an application in Ember, and this "computed property" never actually gets computed by the `if` block helper in the template.

Model:

```
var item = App.Item.create({
    isAddedToCart: function () {
        console.log('addedToCart method has been called');
        return false;
    }.property()
});
```

Template:

```
{{#if item.isAddedToCart}}
    {{log 'true'}}
{{else}}
    {{log 'false}}
{{/if}}
```

In my component that is in the template, the `console.log()` never gets called, but the function seems to be tested if it's truth-y or not. Is there something wrong in my approach?

Edit: The application is written in Ember version 1.7 (I know...)

Comment: I don't think you are able to create computed property in ```create({...})```. Can you try it with ```extend({...}).create();``` But this looks like old ember so,...

Comment: Probably you `.set()` the `isAddedToCart` somewhere? With that you override the computed behavior.

Comment: @Lux good answer, but I haven't overridden the property anywhere, it's strictly for read use.

Comment: @Keo it is old, 1.7. I updated the question, but it's bugging me like crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Which versions you are currently using, actually i tried what you did in ember version 1.12.2 and I got the following assertions which clearly explains how to solve it.

> Error while processing route: index Assertion Failed: Ember.Object.create no longer supports defining computed properties. Define computed properties using extend() or reopen() before calling create(). Error: Assertion Failed: Ember.Object.create no longer supports defining computed properties. Define computed properties using extend() or reopen() before calling create().

I created [sample twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/261cfd6ac8bf7e370740ed27bf04974c?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C) to demonstrate the usage,

controllers/application.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

var App.Item = Ember.Object.extend({    
});
App.Item.reopen({
  isAddedToCart: function () {
        console.log('addedToCart method has been called');
        return false;
    }.property()
});
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  appName: 'Ember Twiddle ',
  itemObj : App.Item.create(),
});
```

and in application.hbs,

```
{{itemObj.isAddedToCart}}
```

May be for earlier version if the ember allows what you did, there might be below problem,
- ensure `item` property is accessible in template
- check for overriding any place or manual set for `isAddedToCart`

Comment: Thank you. I would be lucky at this point to be using 1.12. The application is currently written in 1.7, which I don't think has deprecated that method. I'll update the question

Comment: @SimonStiph updated my answer, in a way how you can refactor your code..Is there any bottleneck for refactoring your code?..anyway down the line when you upgrade you will come to this refactoring code.